# Determine a formule for $\phi(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{50} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ is a group homomorphism with $\phi(7)=3$.

(a) Determine $\phi(x)$

(b) Determine the image of $\phi$

(c) Determine the kernel of $\phi$.

(d) Determine $\phi^{-1}(3)$. 
[image]

**Why is the Kernel such that $5|x$?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know $\phi(1)$ you would have it.

In this case it is fairly quick to find $\phi(49),$ where $49$ is the inverse of $1$ in this group

Comment: added an edit above

Comment: @rover2 you know $\phi(7).$ What is $\phi(35) \; \; ?$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\varphi(7) = \varphi(1 + 1 + 1 + \cdots + 1) = \varphi(1) + \varphi(1) + \cdots + \varphi(1) = 7\cdot \varphi(1)$$

Same thing goes for $\varphi(x)$. What is the multiplicative inverse of $7$ modulo $15$?

**For your edit:** I'm already going to suppose that you've figured out the formula $\varphi(x) \equiv 9x \pmod{15}$. The kernel consists of those $x$ satisfying $\varphi(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{15}$, which amounts to $15$ dividing $9x$. Now, $15$ divides $9x$ if and only if $5$ divides $x$.

Comment: added an edit above

Comment: @rover2 is it clearer now?

Comment: i figured out that the formula was $\phi(x)\equiv 3x(\bmod15)$ ..

Comment: i will add my work for that above if you want